# How to stop watch on firebase child _added

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I'm watching new value depending on a date, thus when the date move I would like to unbind the old child_added and recreate a new one.

```
firebaseRef.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
  // code to handle new child.
});
```

How can I unwatch new data on old ref?

Comment: See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-detaching-callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Firebase.off()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/off.html) on the old reference.